# CTE query not returning duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

For auditing purposes, I use triggers to insert changes into an audit table. I then use a CTE to recursively get all audit rows of a particular item.

This [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e1eb) adds a few audit rows and the CTE that I'm currently using.

Here is the CTE:

```
;WITH cteAudit AS
(
    SELECT id, [user_name], date_time, item_parent_type, item_parent_id, 
        item_type, item_id, item_action, row_guid, 1 AS audit_level
    FROM audit
    WHERE 
        (item_type = 22 AND item_id = 925) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.id, a.[user_name], a.date_time, a.item_parent_type, a.item_parent_id, 
          a.item_type, a.item_id, a.item_action, a.row_guid, cteAudit.audit_level + 1
    FROM audit a
        INNER JOIN cteAudit
            ON a.item_parent_id = cteAudit.item_id
            AND a.item_parent_type = cteAudit.item_type
    WHERE 
        a.item_parent_type <> a.item_type AND
        a.item_parent_id <> a.item_id   
)

SELECT
    cteAudit.id,
    cteAudit.[user_name],
    cteAudit.date_time,
    cteAudit.item_parent_id,
    @itemtype AS item_type,
    cteAudit.item_id,
    item_action,
    cteAudit.audit_level,
    CONVERT(nvarchar(36), cteAudit.row_guid) AS row_guid
ORDER BY date_time DESC, audit_level desc
```

However, with this CTE I have 2 problems:

1. The query does not return all 13 rows. It doesn't show rows 11-13. This is because the main table (customer) wasn't audited because the user just changed the address of a contact person.

This happens because I modified the 3rd level (contact person) and this level has a link to the 2nd level (contact list. However the 2nd level, which has the link to the 1st level (customer), was not modified and therefore is not in the audit table and therefore there's no link to the 1st level.

2. The query returns duplicate records.

How can I return all rows for the main table? And why is the query return duplicate rows?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from either incorrect query or incorrect data.

You ask your recursive query for these constraint:

```
WHERE 
        a.item_parent_type <> a.item_type AND
         a.item_parent_id <> a.item_id
```

but for row 11 - 13, `item_parent_id` equals `item_id`

You also ask for 
`AND a.item_parent_type = cteAudit.item_type`
but for row 11 - 13 your types are flipped and therefore incorrect.

Comment: Well depending on what you changed the data to, then it's likely allowing a row to bind to itself. If you select the parent id out as well it makes it easier to debug